# SparkSession with hive support do not make sql query to remote hive database

Tags: hive

I want to connect to a remote hive database from Windows with sparksession and make an sql query, but my program hangs on:

```
INFO metastore: Connected to metastore.
```

What could can be the reason?

```
public class TestConnectionSpark {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "D:\\Hadoop");

        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "src/test/resources/ConnectToHbase/krb5.ini");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");

        //System.setProperty from
        //hive-site
        //core-site
        //hdfs-site


        SparkSession ss = SparkSession.builder().
                appName("TestHiveContext").master("local")
                .config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
                .config("hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories", "true")
                .config("mapred.input.dir.recursive", "true")
                .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
                .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate();


        Dataset<Row> params = ss.sql("select * from test.test").toDF();

        params.show(10, false);
}
```

Expected result: the dataset is shown

Actual result: logging stoped at `INFO metastore: Connected to metastore.` and the program hangs

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out the application is worked. After hanging on "Connected to metastore" step for about 12 minutes it work further and made the query. But why it works so long I don't understand